# How to change Border width in MatPlotLib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, border, customization

I know how to make border visible/non-visible and color-full [(Graph With Customized borders)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6HNJe.png)

but I don't know how to change width of borders can someone help me out in this

Answer (score 4):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

for axis in ['top', 'bottom', 'left', 'right']:

ax.spines[axis].set_linewidth(2.5)  # change width
ax.spines[axis].set_color('red')    # change color

plt.show()
```

[image: thin red]

[image: thick blue]